# Find minimum element in a rotated array

Tags: java, algorithm, array, search

Here's an implementation of finding the minimum element in a rotated array using binary search (one that is sorted in ascending order, and all elements are distinct).

Please let me know of any improvements that can be made to it.

```
import java.util.List;

public class RotatedArray {
    /**
     * Finds and returns the index at which the smallest value in a rotated array is located.
     *
     * @param rotatedArray    a rotated array that's sorted in ascending order (all elements are distinct)
     * @return the index of the smallest value, or -1 if rotatedArray is empty
     */
    public int findReset(List<Integer> rotatedArray) {
        if (rotatedArray.isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        }

        // when array is already sorted
        if (rotatedArray.size() == 1 || rotatedArray.get(0) < rotatedArray.get(rotatedArray.size() - 1)) {
            return 0;
        }

        int midpoint = rotatedArray.size() / 2;

        // when left side is monotonically increasing
        if (rotatedArray.get(0) < rotatedArray.get(midpoint)) {
            return findReset(rotatedArray.subList(midpoint + 1, rotatedArray.size())) + midpoint + 1;
        }

        // Prevents stack overflow error from occurring (e.g. test case [1,2,3,4,0])
        if (rotatedArray.size() == 2) {
            return midpoint;
        }

        // when right side is monotonically increasing
        return findReset(rotatedArray.subList(0, midpoint + 1));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The method should be `static`.
2. The method should throw `NoSuchElementException` when the list is empty.
3. I prefer to index by `[left, right)` instead of using `subList`
4. Choose a good pivot location, and you don't need the `size() == 2`.

In code:

```
    public static int findReset(List<Integer> rotatedArray) {
        if (rotatedArray.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No reset for an empty list");
        }
        return findReset0(rotatedArray, 0, rotatedArray.size());
    }
    private static int findReset0(List<Integer> rotatedArray, int left, int right) {
        // when array is already sorted
        if(left + 1 == right || rotatedArray.get(left) < rotatedArray.get(right - 1))
            return left;
        int middle = (left + right) / 2;
        if (rotatedArray.get(left) <= rotatedArray.get(middle - 1)) {
            // when left side is monotonically increasing
            return findReset0(rotatedArray, middle, right);
        } else {
            // when right side is monotonically increasing
            return findReset0(rotatedArray, left, middle);
        }
    }
```

Here is a version with manual tail recursion optimization:

```
    public static int findReset(List<Integer> rotatedArray) {
        if (rotatedArray.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No reset for an empty list");
        }
        int left = 0, right = rotatedArray.size();
        while(left + 1 < right && rotatedArray.get(left) >= rotatedArray.get(right - 1)) {
            int middle = (left + right) / 2;
            if (rotatedArray.get(left) <= rotatedArray.get(middle - 1)) {
                // when left side is monotonically increasing
                left = middle;
            } else {
                // when right side is monotonically increasing
                right = middle;
            }
        }
        return left;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for `[left, right)`. Should you also eliminate the recursion, it'd be perfect dissection.

Comment: @vnp *Manual tail recursion optimization is left as exercise for readers*. Just joking. Non-recursive version is now provided.

Comment: @johnchen902 thanks for this! Great feedback. Is it better to use the second implementation? If so, is that because it's easier to read? Recursion is often used in QuickSort and MergeSort so I thought it was a good idea to use it.

Also, could u expand on point 4 please? I'm not sure how to improve on the pivot choice.

Comment: @johnchen902 Also, I noticed that the manual tail recursion implementation doesn't work properly, unless one changes from `middle - 1` to `middle` and `middle` to `middle + 1`. I think this is because that there's a potential situation where `left` and `middle - 1` refer to the same index. Making the changes suggested guarantees this to not be the case (step through test case `[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]` for example). Nonetheless, it's an excellent algorithm.

Comment: @Calculus5000 Actually, both implementation has the bug. Even `[2, 1]` can expose it. Using `<=` instead of `<` should fix it. (As shown by my current code)

Comment: @Calculus5000 Also, I like the first version (with recursion) more.

Comment: @Calculus5000 A good pivot always divides problem sized `n` to sub-problem sized `n/2` and `(n+1)/2`, so it will eventually go down to sub-problem sized `1`.